# .NET framework version 4.7.2 is not compatible with Microsoft.Net.Httpclient NuGet Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, .net-framework-version

I'm using .net framework 4.7.2 for asp.net web application using web api, but once I installed Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package for HttpClient, it made the.net framework to 2.0 version, I want to know is there any requirement to install microsoft.net.http NuGet Package with the updated version of .net framework because before installing this package there was no issue with Httpclient in my code. If It doesn't need to install this package then How to change the current .net framework version i.e 2.1 to the latest version of .net framework.

[image: Target Framework dropdown showing only .NET Standard]

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2 should have an HttpClient class built in, System.Net.Http.HttpClient. You shouldn't need to install any packages. I'd guess the usage will be very similar to the Microsoft.Net.Http version, so you hopefully won't have to change any code to use it instead.

Comment: yes Now I came to know that there is no need to install this package but now the problem is the installation of that package make my .net version to 2.0 so how to make it the latest version i.e 4.7.2

Comment: Oh, you just need to change the framework version? Right click the project in Visual Studio, Properties, Application tab, and there's a 'Target framework' setting near the top.

Comment: in that dropdown list its showing up to .net standard 2.1 only. I have added a screenshot in my question you can go through that.

Comment: .Net Standard 2.0 should be compatible with .net framework 4.7.2. Just change your class library to .net standard 2.0 and you should be able to use it in your .net fdamework project(s)

Comment: Standard 2.1 is not compatible with framework, Standard  2.0 is, just an FYI..., requirement for microsoft.net.http  should be stated on the package from Nuget... you cant simply change dotnet target types... this is a bad question as your mixing issues... simply use the  Framework 4.7.2 HttpClient class built in.

Answer (score 0):

In the NuGet package manager console run `Update-Package  -Reinstall`  This will update the NuGet package references to match the framework version of the project.